# Deploying application to two different servers, with different production.rb contents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, capistrano

I'm deploying my application using **capistrano** for two different servers of **production** mode, but I need to vary some contents in `production.rb` for each server.

2 Possible ways I know.

I feel both are little heavy for a couple of lines change.

- Using different branch(git) for each. - Worried about maintenance.
- Creating a different environment.

How to deal with this situation, a simpler one choose from or new a way?

Rails 3 and Cap 2

**Edit**: I was also suggested to **Use ENV variables or include a file elsewhere on the server**

Comment: Both the environments are not `Production`, right? Best to create a second, different environment (still in Production mode). General practice is to have a separate `Staging` env or a `QA` env. Depending on the purpose of the second env, you can name it what you want. For ex, I have set up a `Upgrade` env specifically for upgrading ruby & rails versions of the app.

Comment: both are `production` env., I should create a different env u suggest ?

Comment: Why would you need 2 `production` environments for the same app? Is it two servers acting as production app servers for load-balancing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using different branch(git) for each.

Do it this way if and only if:

- You want each of the server apps to have markedly different features, and the features interfere with each other i.e. there is no easy way to use a server-specific feature flag.
- For example, if one server is an alpha-test for new code, and one server is a beta-test for new code.

> Creating a different environment.

Do it this way if and only if:

- You want each of the server apps to have markedly different experiences.
- For example, if one server is a demonstration server for trade shows and thus gets wiped often, and one server is your real site for customers.

> Use ENV variables

This is the best way.

Use the [dotenv gem](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) or similar [figaro gem](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/figaro).

"dotenv solves the problems of setting project-specific environment vars and is super easy to get started on. Start by including the gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test] in the appropriate groups, in this case development and test. You can then put your sensitive information inside a .env file at the root of your project directory"

"Figaro is similar to dotenv. What it does is to allow you to store all your sensitive secrets in a YAML file at config/application.yml. With it’s simple figaro install command you get your YAML file automatically added to gitignore. Figaro is built with deployment to Heroku in mind. There is a handy configuration to help set values from your configuration file. It also provides helpful information on deploying to other hosts."

Credit: [Managing Environment Configuration in Rails](http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/managing-environment-configuration-variables-in-rails)